# xslt captalize each word ignore conjunctions

Tags: xslt

i've the below xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter num="A">
    <title>
        <content-style font-style="bold">PART 1 GENERAL PRINCIPLES</content-style>
    </title>
    <section level="sect1">
    <section level="sect2" number-type="manual" num="1.">
            <title>INTRODUCTION OF INDIA TO NEW ERA AND THE EXISTING</title>
            </section>
            </section>
            </chapter>
```

by using the below xslt i'm able to captalize each word.

```
 <xsl:element name="{concat(translate(substring(name(), 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), substring(name(), 2))}">
```

and i get the below output.

```
Introduction Of India To New Era And The Existing
```

but i want as below.

```
Introduction of India to New Era and the Existing
```

i.e. i want to ignore the conjunctions. please let me know how do i do it.

Thanks

Comment: The xslt shown in your question is actually capitalising the first letter of the element name, and will not affect the text. Can you show the XSLT you are currently using to capitalise the text? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim i'm using below xslt <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($text,1,1), translate(substring($text,2), $uppercase, $smallcase))"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piggybacking on the answer provided by @NavinRawat, here's an XSLT 1.0 variant. Note that it requires the use of the [`EXSLT Extension Library's`](http://www.exslt.org/) [`node-set()`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) function.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="pConjunctions" select="'|OF|TO|AND|THE|'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vUppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/title">
    <xsl:variable name="vTitleWords">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($vTitleWords)/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="token">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"> </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($pConjunctions, concat('|', ., '|'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $vUppercase, $vLowercase)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="concat(
            substring(., 1, 1),
            translate(substring(., 2), $vUppercase, $vLowercase)
          )"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$delimiter)">
        <xsl:element name="token">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param
            name="text"
            select="substring-after($text,$delimiter)"/>
          <xsl:with-param
            name="delimiter"
            select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$text">
        <xsl:element name="token">
          <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is run against the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter num="A">
  <title>
    <content-style font-style="bold">PART 1 GENERAL PRINCIPLES</content-style>
  </title>
  <section level="sect1">
    <section level="sect2" number-type="manual" num="1.">
      <title>INTRODUCTION OF INDIA TO NEW ERA AND THE EXISTING</title>
    </section>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
Introduction of India to New Era and the Existing
```

Obviously, the XSLT 2.0 variant is much cleaner and doesn't require a two-pass transformation, but if you're stuck with XSLT 1.0 and can utilize EXSLT, this will get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation uses the `strSplit-to-Words` template of the FXSL library (written in pure XSLT 1.0) and doesn't require any extension functions with the exception of the de-facto standard `xxx:node-set()`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
  <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vUppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vConjunctions" select=
  "'|AND|THE|OF|A|AN|TO|FOR|AT|ON|IN|INTO|AMONG|FROM|'"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="pDelims" select="' &#xA;&#xD;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                          select="$pDelims"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*[normalize-space()]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($vConjunctions, concat('|',.,'|'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(., 1, 1), $vUppercase, $vLowercase)"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 1)"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(., 2), $vUppercase, $vLowercase)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<title>INTRODUCTION OF INDIA TO NEW ERA AND THE EXISTING</title>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Introduction of India to New Era and the Existing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xslt:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="Conjunction">(of)|(to)|(and)|(the)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="chapter/section/section/title">
    <xsl:call-template name="changeUpperCase">
      <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="changeUpperCase">
    <xsl:param name="Text"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $EachToken in tokenize(lower-case($Text), ' ')
                          return
                          if(matches($EachToken, $Conjunction))
                           then
                             $EachToken
                           else
                           concat(upper-case(substring($EachToken, 1, 1)), substring($EachToken, 2))"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xslt:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution,but, can i please have it in xslt1.0?

Comment: I you want to make it for 1.0, you need to edit two things only:

First, Instead of tokenize create your templat to break your string from space, you may use substring after with total word count.
Second, For upper-case you may use translate function, as you have done earlier.